# Eating olives at the house of a mourner

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mourning-aveilus, eating, fruits

Eating olives at the house of a mourner is a custom among Sephardim. I think it is specifically a Morroccan custom. Is there a source or reason for this?

Comment: As far as I have heard it's because they are bitter and round.

Comment: Maybe it's to help forget and move on